# How to view multi line output in emacs?

Tags: emacs

I'm using GNU Emacs 22.2.1. I usually use a different editor, but am learning lisp so I thought there was no better editor to use than emacs. My program outputs several lines of text but I can only ever see the last line because the output area is only one line tall.

I've googled around and wasted about 30 minutes so I figured I would ask. So far I have tried
    C-x ^

in the mini buffer, which increases it by one line -- and then shrinks to one when I go back to my main buffer.

Comment: Emacs 22 is old. If you're just getting started with Emacs, you should start with the latest version of Emacs 23, or try the latest pretest release of Emacs 24 (which is also very stable).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is "my program", is it a Emacs-Lisp defun?

Assuming it is, you must be calling `message` multiple times?  The minibuffer is only for transient output.  So you can either concatenate all your output strings and call `message` once at the end or create a temporary buffer to present the output.

There is also the "*Messages*" buffer, which contains a log of minibuffer outputs.  <kbd>C-x b</kbd> "*Messages*"

Comment: Yes just some functions. Thanks for the tip about the messages buffer

Answer (score 1):

If you're playing with Elisp and want to see their output in a full buffer, you may like `M-x ielm`.